# Rigid body moving orientation relative to helical trajectory

Tags: differential-geometry, analytic-geometry, rotations, curves, rigid-transformation

A rigid sphere moves on a trajectory, made up of points that come out of a mechanical simulation.

To a visual inspection, the trajectory is helical. I calculate the axis $\boldsymbol{N}$ by using the average of tangent vectors between an integer number of turns of the helix. 
I then estimate the radius $R$ by projecting each of the points onto the plane perpendicular to $\boldsymbol{N}$, and fitting them to a circle.
Therefore I know the approximate axis $\boldsymbol{N}$ and radius $R$ of the helix.

I want to be able to check whether a certain section of the sphere is constantly facing the axis of the helix, or away from it. By "a section" I mean a certain circular patch on the surface of the helix.

If I define this patch $S$, I can calculate the normal at its centre $\boldsymbol{r}_0$ as $\boldsymbol{n}_S(r_0)$. 
What's the best quantity to study to investigate the relative orientation between the sphere and helix axis $\boldsymbol{k}$?

The dot product between $\boldsymbol{k}$ and as $\boldsymbol{n}_S(r_0(t))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\alpha\colon I\subset \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^3$ is the parametrization of of the helicoidal trajectory, i.e. the position of the centre of the sphere in function of the time. Call the helix's radius $\rho$. Then for every $t$ the point
$$
   \alpha(t) + \rho N(t)
$$
lies the on the axis of the helix. Here $N(t)$ is the normal vector field along $\alpha$. The *direction* of $N(t)$ is given by
$$
   \alpha''(t) - \left\langle \alpha''(t), \frac{\alpha'(t)}{\|\alpha'(t)\| }\right\rangle \frac{\alpha'(t)}{\|\alpha'(t)\|}.
$$
If you want to get the unit vector $N(t)$, you still need to divide it by its length.
In mechanical terms, $N(t)$ points in the direction of the *normal* acceleration of the curve $\alpha$, hence we subtract the tangent acceleration from $\alpha''(t)$.
If the speed of $\alpha$ is constant, then the formula for $N(t)$ is easier:
$$
  N(t) = \frac{\alpha''(t)}{\|\alpha''(t)\|}.
$$
So for a small patch $S$ a good quantity might be
$$
   \langle n_S(r_0(t)), N(t) \rangle.
$$
The closer this quantity lies to one, the more the patch faces the axis.

**Update:** If you don't know the trajectory, but do know the axis, you can find $N(t)$ as you suggested in the comments. Say $k$ is the unit direction of the axis and $q$ is any point on the axis. At a point $p$ approximately on the helix, the vector
$$
    (p-q) - \langle (p-q), k \rangle.
$$ 
points to the axis. The length of this vector should be approximately $R$.

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot. One of the problems I would have using this, though, is that I only know the points that lie on the helix, not its parametrisation per se. I do evidently see a helical  trajectory by eye when plotting the scattered points, and if I make the sphere move along the line that joins the points it moves on a helical trajectory, but I do not have its parametrisation.

Comment: Okay, that's interesting. Can you add in your question what you exactly know (the axis' direction? the radius $r$) and what the context is (How do you obtain the points? Are you generating points, or are you measuring them?). The first thing I am thinking about is to use regression to determine the best fitting helicoidal... but that is probably going to be overkill if we have at least some information about the helix.

Comment: Updated the main question, thanks! Yes, that's exactly what I am trying to avoid: regression. But perhaps it's the best way to go... Could I, say, calculate the vector perpendicular to the axis that joins the centre of the sphere to the axis itself, and then use the dot product between this and $n_S(r_0(t))?$

Comment: Thanks. The way you suggest is indeed the way to go. I updated my answer.